# OpenUri causing 401 Unauthorized error with HTTPS URL

Tags: ruby, authentication, https, screen-scraping

I am adding functionality that scrapes an XML page from a source that requires the use of an HTTPS connection with authentication. I am trying to use Ryan Bates' Railscast #190 solution but I'm running into a 401 Authentication error.

Here is my test Ruby script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "https://biblesearch.americanbible.org/passages.xml?q[]=john+3:1-5&version=KJV"
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url, :http_basic_authentication => ['username' ,'password']))
puts doc.xpath("//text_preview")
```

Here is the output of the console after I run my script:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `block in connect'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:306:in `open_http'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:775:in `buffer_open'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:203:in `block in open_loop'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `catch'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:201:in `open_loop'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:677:in `open'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:33:in `open'
from scrape.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

In my research, I saw one post in which it was suggested that in 1.9.3 the following option could be used:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url, :http_basic_authentication => ['username' ,'password'], :ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE))
```

However, this did not work either. I would appreciate some insight into addressing this challenge.

Comment: Be careful using `:ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`. That disables the SSL certificate check, which is there to ensure the integrity of the connection, helping avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given URL will be redirected to `/v1/KJV/passages.xml?q[]=john+3%3A1-5` with HTTP status code `302 Found`.  OpenURI understands the redirection, but automatically deletes authentication header (maybe) for security reason. (*)

If you access `"http://biblesearch.americanbible.org/v1/KJV/passages.xml?q[]=john+3%3A1-5"` directly, you will get the expected result. :-)

(*) You can find in `open-uri.rb`:

```
if redirect
  ### snip ###
  if options.include? :http_basic_authentication
    # send authentication only for the URI directly specified.
    options = options.dup
    options.delete :http_basic_authentication
  end
```

Comment: If I remember right, security headers have to be deleted when a redirection is from a secure to a non-secure URL. It was a hole or exploit that was found several years ago and fixed in clients, not just OpenURI. It should be automatically handled by OpenURI.

Comment: Basic authentication header will be removed **even if redirected from HTTPS to HTTPS** as of ruby 1.9.3p286 (newest stable version).  Check open-uri.rb for detail.

Comment: Thank you, @HIRATA Yasuyuki! I see now that read only does not require authentication, only RESTful writing does. Pointing to the URL you specified works fine now. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this and it should work too:

`open(url,  :http_basic_authentication => [user, pass] )
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url, :http_basic_authentication => [user, pass] ))`

You can then parse the doc anyway you want. 
By passing the http_basic_authentication in the header again in the second request, you will make up for the deleted header in the first request.
hope this works for you.

http://http-basic-authentication-nokogiri.blogspot.com/2014/08/http-basic-authentication-using-nokogiri.html

Answer (score 1):

You say you need to use HTTPS, but you're using the HTTP protocol:

```
url = "http://biblesearch...."
```

OpenURI understands both HTTP and HTTPS. If you want to connect using HTTPS, change the protocol in the URL to `HTTPS`, then make the connection:

```
url = "https://biblesearch...."
```

Comment: Yes, sorry. I updated the code and the output. It appears that there is now an issue verifying the certificate. Researching...