# Replace BASH curl with Ruby equivalent

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, curl, open-uri

I am trying to replace piece of shell curl in my ruby with something more native like 'open-uri', but failing and getting: '401 Authorization Required'

I'm trying to replace this:

```
status = system("curl -Is -w '%{http_code}\\n' --digest -u #{usr}:#{psw} https://#{source}/ -o /dev/null")
```

With this:

```
require 'open-uri'

status = open("https://#{source}/", :http_basic_authentication=>[usr, psw])
```

But still getting 401. Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you hit any redirects, [this could be your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765887/2128691):

```
if redirect
  ...
  if options.include? :http_basic_authentication
    # send authentication only for the URI directly specified.
    options = options.dup
    options.delete :http_basic_authentication
  end
end
```